# Refactoring Similar Code Across Data Types

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I am working in Java, inserting data from HashMaps of certain types into a SQL database. It has produced some code like this:

```
for ( String key : strings.keySet() ) {
    result_set.updateString(key, strings.get(key));
}

for ( String key : booleans.keySet() ) {
    result_set.updateBoolean(key, booleans.get(key));
}

for ( String key : dates.keySet() ) {
    result_set.updateDate(key, dates.get(key));
}
```

I am used to Ruby, where code like this would take up one line and I can't believe I have to do it like this in Java. I must be wrong. Is there a better way? I assume using Generics? I tried using result_set.updateObject(key, object) but it gave me "SQLException: Unable to convert between java.util.Date and VARCHAR."

Comment: not really.  There may be other ways to achieve what you want to achieve in your specific case, but using pure Java (i.e. no pre-processor and no other JVM language) you're pretty much forced to visit "verbose-land" in quite some cases.  For example (it's not identical, but it's related) if you want to implement, say, Goldberg's floating point comparison (using an epsilon), you have to write the method once for double and once for float.  In some case you have to repeat this for all the primitives types.  In Ruby or Scala this is a no-brainer and requires no repetition.

Comment: note that some projects are using code-generators to dodge Java code repetition.  The excellent Java Trove library, if I'm not mistaken, is using such a code-generator.

Comment: How disappointing. Great comments though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/), an SQL Mapper that handles the mapping between POJOs (including Maps and Lists) and SQL.  It's saved us a ton of work relative to what it would take to do everything ourselves in raw JDBC.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look when I get back to work tomorrow. Thanks!